# Create scatterplot in pandas using row as index and row as data

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

First off, let me say that I just began using the pandas module a few days ago, so apologies if there is a simple solution to this that I was unaware of. I am trying to make a scatterplot in pandas using a specific row as the index (for the x-axis) and a specific row for the data to be plotted. I want this to be executed across all columns. Example:

```
df:
      col1  col2  col3
0     0     0    -1
1     0.88  1     8.12
2     1    -1     1
3     0     0     0
4     0.3   1    3.4
```

So, the idea is to create a scatterplot using 4 as the index (x-axis) and 1 as the data (y axis) where every column represents a point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [3]: df.T.plot(kind='scatter', x=4, y=1)
```

The `.T` transposes the matrix, so `4` is now the column you use as the `x` axis.

Comment: Is there any way to give a name for the plot?

Comment: Also, is there any way to skip the first two columns, exuding them from the plot?